# Dynamically change the layout of the WPF app to show one or two components on the grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, gridview

I have a WPF app with a main view of a treelist and I also want to be able to open a second component when I press on a button (and hide it when pressed again).

But I cannot make the second component to take the needed space and the tree view the rest, without overlapping.

In XAML, I declared a grid with 5 rows as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <views:InputsControl Grid.Row="0"/>

    <views:TreeViewControl Grid.Row="1" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Height="3" 
          Visibility="{Binding LoggerVisibility}" >
    </GridSplitter>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="3"
             BorderThickness="1"
             Margin="2 ,0, 2, 2"
             IsReadOnly="True"
             Visibility="{Binding LoggerVisibility}">
        Some logger info
    </TextBox>

    <views:StatusBar Grid.Row="4"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
private Visibility _LoggerVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
public Visibility LoggerVisibility
{
    get => _LoggerVisibility;
    set
    {
        _LoggerVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LoggerVisibility));
    }
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<Actions>(this, ProcessAction);
}

private void ProcessAction(Actions action)
{
    if (action == Actions.ToggleLogger)
    {
        if (LoggerVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            LoggerVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (LoggerVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            LoggerVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the app looks like:

when it's first run
[image]

after the first button click
[image]

after the second button click
[image]

So I want it to go the the layout in the first photo after the second click.

I noticed that I can get my desired behavior, in separate steps, if I change the row span for the tree list view row. If the logger is visible, the code from above works perfectly fine. If the logger is closed and I add Grid.RowSpan = "3" to the treelist row, is also looks good. So I figured I can bind the value of the rowspan in code behind and keep it synced with `LoggerVisibility` which is also toggled in code behind when the button is pressed.

But for some reason, the rowspan is not updated. I supposed the way I bind it is correct, since I did the same thing for the `LoggerVisibility` binding, and it does its job and the logger can indeed be collapsed or visible when the button is pressed.

Can you, please, help me?

Comment: You have to set the height of the row that contains the TextBox to Auto. Otherwise the row heught will renain even when the element is hidden. If necessary you can give the TextBox a fixed height instead. Basically, the row that contains the TreeView should be the only route with a height of "*".

Comment: @BionicCode I set the height of the TextBox row to auto, and solves the overlapping problem. When I click the button, the TextBox component appears and the TreeList size is adapted to fill in the rest of the space, but, unfortunately, when I click the button again and the TextBox dissapears, the TreeList does not take again all the availabale space.

Comment: How do you hide the TextBox? You must set the Visibility to Visibility.Collapsed. Otherwise, the layout engine will preserve the space for the element. The hidden element is still in the element tree, same location, just not rendered (hidden). Only if you collapse it, the element is removed and its reserved space becomes available for other elements.

Comment: It's collapsed, not hidden. So when I first run the app, I only have the treelist, because default value of LoggerVIsibility is Collapsed., so it somehow knows that the textbox is collapsed and the treelist takes all the space. When I click the button, the text box appears, treelist shrinks, and when I click again, the textbox collapses but the treeview remains as is, without expanding again on all the available space. I edited the question and added additional code.

Comment: Thanks for adding more information. Does the tab header belong to the TreeViewControl? Please apply the following steps: 1) Set the height of the 4th row to "Auto" 2) Ensure that the TreeViewControl has its Height set to "Auto". this should give you the desired behavior (after the second click the layout will again look like the second image.

Comment: If this doesn't fix your issue, then the problem must be related to the TreeViewControl. It would be helpful if you could show the layout of this control. If there is some code-behind that implements layout logic please post it too.

Comment: Just in case that it was not clear: do not define any row spans. My suggestions are based on the current version you have posted. There is no row span required.

Comment: I don't use any row span :) I tried your steps but, unfortunately, it does not fix it. Yes, the header belongs to the TreeViewControl, which does not have much behind it, only the following:
    <Grid>
        <TabControl 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

Comment: I have just tried your code and have applied my suggested fixes. I have replaced the TreeViewControl with a simple TreeView wrapped into a TabControl and I can't reproduce your behavior. The layout behaves as expected. That's why it is important that you post the complete layout and related logic. I suggest creating a minimal example that reproduces the issue so that I can review your code properly. There *must* be some detail you have not shown.

Comment: I replaced my TreeViewControl with a TreeView wrapped into a TabControl like you did, and nothing changed. But I noticed smth else. I always moved the grid splitter up after I opened the logger, because it opens up too small, and apparently, that's what makes the treeview not to expand anymore. If I actually close the logger immediately after I open it, I get the expected behaviour, but if I resize the textbox with the grid splitter, not anymore. Maybe, when the grid splitter is moved, it changes the width of the treeview row to a fixed number, even if it is initially set to auto?!

Comment: That's what a grid splitter does. You could set the width back to auto using a trigger.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I was not moving the GridSplitter. Of course, that's exactly what the GridSplitter does, it modifies the adjacent row's/column's height/width. I will post a solution based on a MultiBinding later. I'm busy right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the `GridSpliter` is to redistribute space between rows/columns. It does this by changing the size of its adjacent rows/columns. In other words, the `GridSplitter` overwrites the original values of the `RowDefinition` or `ColumnDefinition`. This means you have to backup the original `GridLength` values and restore them if the `GridSplitter` is collapsed.

The following example shows a simple attached behavior to handle this by setting/binding the `GridSplitterService.IsVisible` attached property on the `GridSplitter`.
Because we can now introduce a boolean property to toggle the visibility from the view model the solution becomes cleaner in terms of MVVM.

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
private bool isLoggerEnabled;
public bool IsLoggerEnabled
{
    get => this.isLoggerEnabled;
    set
    {
        this.isLoggerEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsLoggerEnabled));
    }
}

private void ProcessAction(Actions action)
{
  if (action == Actions.ToggleLogger)
  {
    // Simply toggle the boolean value using XOR
    this.IsLoggerEnabled ^= true;     
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>

    <!-- use the built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter -->
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Grid.Resources>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <views:InputsControl Grid.Row="0"/>

  <views:TreeViewControl Grid.Row="1" />

  <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Height="3" 
                GridSplitterService.IsVisible="{Binding IsLoggerEnabled}" />

  <!-- Consider to use the lightweight TextBlock instead -->
  <TextBox Grid.Row="3"
           BorderThickness="1"
           Margin="2 ,0, 2, 2"
           IsReadOnly="True"
           Visibility="{Binding IsLoggerEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
           Text="Some logger info" />

  <views:StatusBar Grid.Row="4"/>
</Grid>
```

**GridSplitterService.cs**

```cs
public class GridSplitterService : DependencyObject
{
  class BackupInfo
  {
    public BackupInfo(GridLength adjacentPreviousGridLength, GridLength adjacentNextGridLength, DefinitionBase adjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition, DefinitionBase adjacentNextGridElementDefinition)
    {
      this.AdjacentPreviousGridLength = adjacentPreviousGridLength;
      this.AdjacentNextGridLength = adjacentNextGridLength;
      this.AdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition = adjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition;
      this.AdjacentNextGridElementDefinition = adjacentNextGridElementDefinition;
    }

    public void RestoreAdjacentColumns()
    {
      ((ColumnDefinition)this.AdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition).Width = this.AdjacentPreviousGridLength;
      ((ColumnDefinition)this.AdjacentNextGridElementDefinition).Width = this.AdjacentNextGridLength;
    }

    public void RestoreAdjacentRows()
    {
      ((RowDefinition)this.AdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition).Height = this.AdjacentPreviousGridLength;
      ((RowDefinition)this.AdjacentNextGridElementDefinition).Height = this.AdjacentNextGridLength;
    }

    public GridLength AdjacentPreviousGridLength { get; }
    public GridLength AdjacentNextGridLength { get; }
    public DefinitionBase AdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition { get; }
    public DefinitionBase AdjacentNextGridElementDefinition { get; }
  }

  public static bool GetIsVisible(GridSplitter attachingElement) 
    => (bool)attachingElement.GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);

  public static void SetIsVisible(GridSplitter attachingElement, bool value) 
    => attachingElement.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsVisible", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(GridSplitterService), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsVisibleChanged));

  private static ConditionalWeakTable<GridSplitter, BackupInfo> OriginalGridLengthMap { get; }
    = new ConditionalWeakTable<GridSplitter, BackupInfo>();

  private static void OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (attachingElement is not GridSplitter gridSplitter)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException($"Attaching element must be of type {typeof(GridSplitter).FullName}.", nameof(attachingElement));
    }

    bool isResizingRows = gridSplitter.ResizeDirection is GridResizeDirection.Rows
      || gridSplitter.HorizontalAlignment is HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    var host = (Grid)gridSplitter.Parent;

    if (!GridSplitterService.OriginalGridLengthMap.TryGetValue(gridSplitter, out _))
    {
      StoreOriginalGridLengthBeforeGridSplitterResize(gridSplitter, isResizingRows, host);
    }

    bool isVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (isVisible)
    {
      gridSplitter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else if (GridSplitterService.OriginalGridLengthMap.TryGetValue(gridSplitter, out BackupInfo backupInfo))
    {
      gridSplitter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

      if (isResizingRows)
      {
        backupInfo.RestoreAdjacentRows();
      }
      else
      {
        backupInfo.RestoreAdjacentColumns();
      }
    }
  }

  private static void StoreOriginalGridLengthBeforeGridSplitterResize(GridSplitter gridSplitter, bool isResizingRows, Grid host)
  {
    GridLength originalAdjacentPreviousGridLength;
    GridLength originalAdjacentNextGridLength;
    DefinitionBase originalAdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition;
    DefinitionBase originalAdjacentNextGridElementDefinition;

    if (isResizingRows)
    {
      int gridSplitterRowIndex = Grid.GetRow(gridSplitter);
      int gridSplitterTopRowIndex = gridSplitterRowIndex - 1;
      int gridSplitterBottomRowIndex = gridSplitterRowIndex + 1;

      originalAdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition = host.RowDefinitions[gridSplitterTopRowIndex];
      originalAdjacentPreviousGridLength = ((RowDefinition)originalAdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition).Height;
      originalAdjacentNextGridElementDefinition = host.RowDefinitions[gridSplitterBottomRowIndex];
      originalAdjacentNextGridLength = ((RowDefinition)originalAdjacentNextGridElementDefinition).Height;
    }
    else
    {
      int gridSplitterColumnIndex = Grid.GetColumn(gridSplitter);
      int gridSplitterLeftColumnIndex = gridSplitterColumnIndex - 1;
      int gridSplitterRigthColumnIndex = gridSplitterColumnIndex + 1;

      originalAdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition = host.ColumnDefinitions[gridSplitterLeftColumnIndex];
      originalAdjacentPreviousGridLength = ((ColumnDefinition)originalAdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition).Width;
      originalAdjacentNextGridElementDefinition = host.ColumnDefinitions[gridSplitterRigthColumnIndex];
      originalAdjacentNextGridLength = ((ColumnDefinition)originalAdjacentNextGridElementDefinition).Width;
    }

    var backupInfo = new BackupInfo(originalAdjacentPreviousGridLength, originalAdjacentNextGridLength, originalAdjacentPreviousGridElementDefinition, originalAdjacentNextGridElementDefinition);
    GridSplitterService.OriginalGridLengthMap.Add(gridSplitter, backupInfo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That exactly what I wanted. 
One mention, however: the datatype of the IsLoggerEnabled in ViewModel.cs should be bool also, not Visibility :D

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have copied that from your example and forgot to modify it. There were XAML typos too ;)